# Create Token for Credit Card from Globalcollect Payment Gateway Api

Tags: c#, json, paypal, payment-gateway

I am trying to create `token` on Globalcollect payment Gateway. I can't figure out my issue.

My Request as JSON:

```
{
    "paymentProductId": 705,
    "card": {
        "alias": null,
        "customer": {
            "billingAddress": {
                "additionalInfo": null,
                "city": "fasdfasdf",
                "countryCode": "MX",
                "houseNumber": null,
                "state": null,
                "stateCode": null,
                "street": null,
                "zip": "23423"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "cardWithoutCvv": {
                "cardNumber": "4567-3500-0042-7977",
                "cardholderName": "test",
                "expiryDate": "1220",
                "issueNumber": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the `UNKNOWN DATATYPE CREDITCARDNUMBER` Issue:-

```
  {
       "errorId" : "589ea6d9-9047-4b20-bd33-41f06d27e52b",
       "errors" : [ {
          "code" : "21000000",
          "requestId" : "388215",
          "message" : "UNKNOWN DATATYPE CREDITCARDNUMBER",
          "httpStatusCode" : 500
       } ]
    }
```

Thanks..!

Comment: Have you considered sending the creditcard without dashes? Is that completely according to documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but that is also returns the same message.